# Need of normalization of count data from different size?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, data-visualization, sample-size, normalization, standardization

I've counted the ecological value of each tree on 7 plots. Now I would like to represent the cumulative ecological value on each of these plots.

The problem that my colleague pointed out is that the number of tree is different between the plots because of the different size of the plots:

1st plot: 52 trees on 0.1 ha

2nd plot: 111 trees on 0.15 ha

3rd plot: 105 trees on 0.4 ha

4th plot: 82 trees on 0.4 ha

5th plot: 152 trees on 0.4 ha

6th plot: 43 trees on 0.15 ha

7th plot: 100 trees on 0.4 ha

The ecological values obtained are almost everytime different between the trees.

I would like to present these results on the same graph, what I did (see below), in order to identify trends.

Is it necessary that I normalize my results? And how?

[image: Cumulative ecological value obtained on each plots]

The green and gray curves represent plots from smaller size, so have less trees. The dark blue curve represent also a plot from smaller size, but still have a lot of trees (because of smaller trees).
The other curves represent plots which have the same size.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your experiment at the moment - what exactly is "cumulative ecological value", and how do you calculate it?

My suggestion would be that you rarefy your data back to the lowest sample size.  Rarefying involves randomly removing trees from your plots, so that all samples have the lowest number of trees (43 in your case), and can therefore be compared.  You can use the function rrarefy in the R package, "vegan".

An alternative would be to estimate the total cumulative ecological value of each plot before comparing them.  People sometimes do this when comparing species richness of sites, estimating the number of 'unseen' species using estimates such as Chao or ACE (also in the vegan R package), although I think rarefying is seen as a more conservative option.

Comment: The "cumulative ecological value" is the cumulation of the ecological value of each tree, by a simple addition of this values.